# How can I get Customer Group Id on Orders View Page?

Tags: orders, customer-group, helper

I am unable to get the correct Customer Group ID from the Order View page. This is part of a helper, which calls

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/sales_order_create')->getQuote()->getCustomerGroupId();
```

and it works fine if it is during the "Create Order" process, but I can't determine how to load the Customer Group on the Order View page after order creation.

**What can I load to get the customer's group id from the order after the order is already created?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already order create that why you can  not use session quote object

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/sales_order_create')->getQuote()->getCustomerGroupId();
```

use **Mage::registry('sales_order')**

**Try this**

```
if(Mage::registry('sales_order') &&(Mage::registry('sales_order')->getId())):
Mage::registry('sales_order')->getCustomerGroupId();
else:
//During creation of an  order
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/sales_order_create')->getQuote()->getCustomerGroupId();
endif;
```